# What am I doing wrong with this regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

```
(?!^\*)\w{1,20}
```

I'm trying to ensure that input is between one and twenty characters long and doesn't begin with '*'. Any other character under the sun is allowed though.

The expression doesn't work in c# but does seem to work using this tester:http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

What do I need to change?

Thanks for any insight on this.

EDIT:
By request, here is the c# code:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex TempRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?!^\*)\w{1,20}");
return TempRegex.IsMatch(_inputString);
```

Comment: `^(?<!\*)\w{1,20}$` -- ?

Comment: You should also post the code that's calling the regex. Maybe you have an option wrong in the compilation or application of it.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong with this regular expression?*: You are using a regular expression. jk kthxbai

Comment: Are you not looking for `^[^*].{0,20}$`, given your any character under the sun remark?

Comment: What's your definition of `any other character under the sun`? Because clearly `\w` doesn't cover everything under the sun (it doesn't include spaces, which clearly exist under the sun).

Comment: Any character... batman, spiderman, etc.... just kidding. Actually, question marks, commas, colon ( probably should reconsider a semi-colon though ), etc is acceptable unless it is '*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do with <strike>first capture</strike>[zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion), but following regular expression seem to match your requirement:

```
@"^[^\*]\w{0,19}$"
```

`"^...$"` portion forces matching of whole string. First character `"[^\*]"` (anything but star) is already counted against [1-20] restriction, so range is {0,19}.

Comment: It's not a capture, it's a negative lookahead assertion (should be lookbehind - that's probably the OP's mistake) --- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks. That first capture was (supposedly) to ensure the string doesn't begin with an asterisk. I have been reading online a while and that was the first thing that I read and tried that got me anywhere.

Comment: @user1064763: you're using lookahead instead of lookbehind - check my first comment to your question

Comment: @zerkms, thanks for info. Luckily :) did not know of this thing.

Comment: Alexei nailed it. The part that is getting me is the exclusion of '*'. I'm going to be studying tonight I suppose :) Thanks a lot for helping me.